# Is it possible to change default english language for localization?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nslocalizedstring

My app support english, german and italy. If use load app with france interface language, app will have english interface.
So is it possible to change default language and how?
I want to make german as a default language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the phone configuration.

When you chose the iPhone language you don't just choose 1 language but an order of all the available language. In France phone are configured like that:

- French
- English
- Spanish
- ...

So if French isn't available, the app is in english.

Answer (score 1):

Open your target, go to the *Info* section, and change *"Localization native development region"* to the language identifier you want to be the default.  If iOS can't find an appropriate localised resource, this value is used as the default.

Comment: So I need to replace en with de in "Localization native development region"?